# How to remove app-malware-virus that's not visible in the app list

Tags: applications, malware, uninstallation, antivirus, unknown-sources

I downloaded an apk from [this site](http://www.basictricks.net/2015/01/get-candy-crush-saga-unlimited-lives-boosters-moves-free.html) that it was supposed to be a modified app for a game (Candy Crush Saga). Here you can find the [download link](http://d-h.st/Vel).

The problem is that not only the app doesn't do what it was claimed to do (i.e. provide you with tricks, unlimited lives, etc) but most importantly it is a malware-virus.

So after installing this app, I get pop up windows with ads.

First of all I removed the apk and tried to search for the installed app through settings. Surprisingly I couldn't find anything apart from the apps I have installed through PlayStore!

Then I installed `Clean Master` and `AVG Antivirus` but neither managed to find any problem.

I also tried using `DEBLOATER` (I installed it through wine on my fedora 25 laptop) but this didn't work either.

I also connected my phone to my laptop and tried to find and delete the bloatware but I wasn't able to find it.

So my question is how can I remove this "app" when it's not visible in the app list?

For reference I am running Android 6.0 and my phone is Oukitel k6000pro and my PC runs fedora 25.

Comment: you can do that with ADB by listing all packages installed on the phone.

Comment: @esQmo : Thank you very much for your comment. Could you provide with a full answer, to possibly help solve future problems? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome. Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @esQmo No unfortunately not :(

Comment: You'll need root access and even busybox installed to be able to remove/delete malwares that are installed on the /system partition

Comment: Try hiding those apps instead: download DEBLOATER (search on Google), enable USB debugging in the Developers options, connect the phone to the computer. Run Deloater, you should see all apps with their packages listed. Check those you want to hide/disable.

Comment: Next time, don't trust any other source than the official one. Download all apps from Google Play.

Comment: @esQmo_ : I've trying really hard to solve this but I couldn't. I couldn't find any debloater to help me without rooting. So I tried to root, but I couldn't either. Do you have any debloater to recommend? Note that I am using linux and not windows.

Comment: The software I told you is called DEBLOATER. I don't onow if there is a Lonux version

Answer (score 0):

You can use DEBLOATER to hide those app because removing require root access. 
Download from [here](http://debloater.en.lo4d.com/).

Learn how to use the software at [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/debloater-remove-carrier-bloat-t2998294)

Note: It's a Windows executable, so you need a Windows machine to be able to use it.

Edit: Drivers can be downloaded [here](http://hexamob.com/driversen/download-android-usb-drivers-for-oukitel/) or [here](http://oukitel.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to install it in Fedora 25 through wine, but it cannot see my phone.

Comment: You need USB drivers for your phone. Did you enable USB debugging?

Comment: USB debugging is on. USB drivers? Hmm... I don't think so. I have no idea what these are, so I'll search about it!

Comment: Added a link to the download area